# why can I see a file by glob.glob(path) but open(path, 'r') can not find the file?

Tags: python, numpy, file, glob, ls

I try to open a file which I can get its information by ls -l in terminal or glob.glob(path) in python, but I can not open() it or np.load() it.
Here are the command,

```
path='xxx'
glob.glob(path)
open(path, 'r')
```

and here are the outputs,

```
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> path = '/data00/home/zhangbowen.17/code/text_rec/dataset/BigAndSmallDataset/cut_100_big_user_video_500_mine_precomp/train_cnn_fea.npy'
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob(path)
['/data00/home/zhangbowen.17/code/text_rec/dataset/BigAndSmallDataset/cut_100_big_user_video_500_mine_precomp/train_cnn_fea.npy']
>>> open(path, 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data00/home/zhangbowen.17/code/text_rec/dataset/BigAndSmallDataset/cut_100_big_user_video_500_mine_precomp/train_cnn_fea.npy'
```

By the way, np.load() has the same result. However, I can get the information by ls -l in terminal.

Comment: What does `glob()` give you if you specify a filename that doesn't exist? The thing I'm wondering is what it does when it gets a pattern that doesn't resolve to anything. Also, the docs contain a note about broken symlinks, which could be a cause.

Comment: it will return []. For example,  if I input 'glob.glob(path+'a')', it outputs '[]'. And I don't quite understand broken symlinks in this question, would you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: What does `ls -l` shows for this file? Maybe it's a broken symlink?

Comment: ls -l shows `lrwxrwxrwx 1 zhangbowen.17 zhangbowen.17 52 Dec  1  2020 /data00/home/zhangbowen.17/code/text_rec/dataset/BigAndSmallDataset/cut_100_big_user_video_500_mine_precomp/train_cnn_fea.npy -> ../../dataset_list/cut100_big_user_train_res_fea.npy`

Comment: So, does the target of the symlink exist? Can you `cat` it?

Comment: oh, I can't `cat` it indeed. What does it mean? I am not faimilar with it.

Comment: I think I get you. It may seem to be a broken symlinks. Thank you both.